# How would I make it so that when someone presses a key, the website closes/redirects to another website

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game website and a feature I would like to add is if someone presses " ` " for example, it closes the page or opens a website.

I have seen it before but I do not remember the website name so that I can see what they did.

Comment: that should do a redirect `document.onkeypress = function (e) { if(e.key == "\`") window.location = "https://www.yahoo.com" };`

Comment: sorry, that's what I ment @derloopkat

Answer (score 0):

Every key has a key code. In your case, for the key ***"`"***, the code is 192. You can Google it.
So what you can do is add an event listener on the 'window" object like so:

```js
window.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);

const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
   let keyCode = e.code;
   if(keyCode === 192) {
   // your logic goes here
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but  if you read the question a bit harder you would have seen the part where I asked how to open a new site on keypress. Thank you tho